# How to make a `text + line-break + link` for sharing on Whatsapp?

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, whatsapp, encodeuricomponent

I tried many approaches online explaining the issue, but didn't find the one could fit with my need.

I want to make a `share to whatsapp` link on my website for each product, including `product name, line-break and link`. Something like this:

```
Product Name [/r/n]
https://....
```

I'm using OpenCart 3. Here is php side code:

```
'whatsapp_text' => $result['manufacturer'] . ' - ' . $result['model'] . ' - ' . $result['name']
    . $this->encodeURIComponent('\r\n' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']))
```

Above code returns this:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Nurinu%20-%201310%20-%20Bra%5Cr%5Cnhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.myweb.com%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dproduct%2Fproduct%26amp%3Bproduct_id%3D61
```

According to this page (https://github.com/kriskbx/whatsapp-sharing/issues/16#issuecomment-294854157) it's possible to use `window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage)` to have a `line-break`, but I don't know how to combine it with my php code or use it in html side:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text={{ product.whatsapp_text }}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Whatsapp</a>
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to include the function (encodeURIComponent):

```
function encodeURIComponent($str) {
$revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
}
```

Comment: `'\r\n'` - that’s not a line break.

Comment: @CBroe: So what should I use instead?

Comment: Your knowledge of the PHP syntax basics …? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Here is the output using `rawurlencode`: Here is the output: Moonlight-263-Bra%5Cnhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dproduct%2Fproduct%26amp%3Bproduct_id%3D55 
Any idea how to make a line break?

Comment: Read the link to the manual that I posted ... and pay attention to the difference between strings enclosed in single, or in double quotes ...

Comment: I think I got the point, but unfortunately still can't fix the issue. I'll be really thankful if you write an answer. I tried this: 'whatsapp_text' => $result['manufacturer'] . urlencode("\n" . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']))

Comment: The link you referred to is talking about using `whatsapp://send?text=`, which is something different than what you are using here. Not sure whether what you want is even possible using the latter; tried a few combinations of differently encoded line breaks, and they were either replaced with simple spaces, or whatsapp even redirected my in my browser to the URL with the line breaks characters completely removed from the parameter.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help. For now I'll stop working on it. Maybe in coming days I'll be more free to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2020

Even though this trend has its years, looking for the same question I got here. So this is for today a current way to go:

> Spaces uses this command: **%20** (but not necessary if inside a PHP variable)
>
> Line breaks: **%0A** or **%0D%0A** (Totally required)
>
> Links: No special character needed

```
$txt_1 = 'You can see there is no need to include special commands for spaces if they  are in a PHP variable.'."%0A";
$txt_2 = 'But you do need to include some inside the variable to jump lines.'."%0D%0A";
$txt_3 = 'And nothing special for links: https://example.com';

$msg= $txt_1.$txt_2.$txt_3."%0A";

<a href="https://wa.me/put_your_number_here?text=<?php echo $msg ?>Spaces%20here%20require%20this."  target="_blank" >
//Some WhatsApp icon
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue according to this article (http://webdevelopmentscripts.com/35-share-a-link-on-whatsapp-from-website) and `CBroe`'s suggestion on using `double quote` for line break `"\n"`:

```
'whatsapp_text' => $result['manufacturer'] . '-' . $result['model'] . '-' . $result['name']
    . rawurlencode("\n" . $this->url->link('product/product&product_id=' . $result['product_id']))

<a href="whatsapp://send?text={{ product.whatsapp_text }}">whatsapp</a>
```

The result is exactly what I want:

```
Moonslictese-251-Bra
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=46
```

Also I could use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
javascript:void(location.href='whatsapp://send?text='+encodeURIComponent({{ product.whatsapp_text }}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlencode($yourmessage)` for same.

Comment: The problem is `line-break` which still is not fixed.

Comment: I tried it too: The same. Here is the output: `Moonlight-263-Bra%5Cnhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dproduct%2Fproduct%26amp%3Bproduct_id%3D55`

Answer (score 0):

i tried with "\\n" (double backslash + n), and it's worked !

i get this from send test message at insomnia (postman like) with php-curl API to whatsapp number.